# Jquery Recursive Object Iteration to build Orgchart

Tags: jquery, object, recursion, orgchart

I have a list of objects representing countries.

Each country has a lit of employees.
Each employee object has it's own properties and a reference to it's manager.

An employee can have an inexistent manager or a manager sitting in a different country.

I'm trying to rebuild a new object with parent child relationships between employees and managers.

```
var Markets = {
"CH":{
        "Resources": {
            "user1": {"First name": "John", "Last name": "Blue", "Job Title": "Job 1", "Email": "john@email", "Manager": ""},               
            "user2": {"First name": "Bob", "Last name": "Black", "Job Title": "Job 2", "Email": "bob@email", "Manager": "user1"},
            "user3": {"First name": "Joe", "Last name": "Brown", "Job Title": "Job 3", "Email": "joe@email", "Manager": "user1"},
            "user4": {"First name": "Jack", "Last name": "White", "Job Title": "Job 4", "Email": "jack@email", "Manager": "user2"}
            "user5": {"First name": "Jess", "Last name": "Red", "Job Title": "Job 5", "Email": "jess@email", "Manager": ""}
        }
    }
```

My new object would therefore look like:

```
user 1
    user 2
    user 3
        user 4
user 5
```

I've come up with the following function but i'm having a hard time making it recursive to ensure it will reassign second level managers to first level.

```
function countryOrgChart(market) {
    var orgChartData = {};
    for (var resource in window['Markets'][market]['Resources']) {
        orgChartData[resource] = [];
    }
    orgCharDataTmp = orgChartData;
    for (var resource in orgCharDataTmp {
        var manager = window['Markets'][market]['Resources'][resource]['Manager'];
        if (manager in orgChartData) { 
            orgChartData[manager].push(resource); 
            delete orgChartData[resource]; 
        }
    }
    return(orgChartData);
```

}

Comment: Can you predict that the manager will be defined before the employees they manage? This will alter the way it is done.

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to be recursive to create it, just to navigate over it after creation.

- Create a look-up of all the users
- Attach employees to managers based on the manager user id
- Display recursively

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/orbp4w3n/5/

```
// Build a dictionary of all employees
var emps = [];

// Iterate the markets
for (var marketkey in Markets) {
    var market = Markets[marketkey];

    // Iterate the departments in a market
    for (var departmentkey in market) {
        var department = market[departmentkey];

        // Iterate the employess in a department
        for (var employeekey in department) {

            // Store the required employee details in an array
            var employee = department[employeekey];
            console.log(employee);
            emps.push({
                user: employeekey,
                manager: employee.Manager,
                employees: []
            });
        }
    }
}

// Also build a list of all employees with no manager
var directors = [];

// Connect the employee to their manager
for (var i = 0; i < emps.length; i++) {
    var employee = emps[i];

    // if the employee has a manager
    if (employee.manager) {

        // Find the manager object
        var mgr = $.grep(emps, function (e) {
            return e.user == employee.manager;
        });
        if (mgr.length) {
            var manager = mgr[0];

            // if found add this employee to their list of employees
            manager.employees.push(employee);

            // get rid of the reference
            delete employee.manager;
        }
    } else {
        directors.push(employee);
    }
}
```

**Note:** *I have not reduced the code, as I am aiming for readability.*